# HEX/Decimal to date and time from modbus

Tags: date, time, modbus

I have a modbus connection to a ventilation system where it generates alarmas when something is wrong. I can with modbus receive data about the alarm. That part is documentated with a register for ID, date and time. All tre receives contains 2 byte of data. ID 00:13 (witch is converted to decimal error code 19 = Filter alarm)

But i cannot figure out what format the date and time are in. However i can at the ventilation system see what these dates and times are translated to at the display.

The date i received in bytes(hex) = 43:68 (17256 in decimal) and thats equals on the display with "13-11-08" (08-nov-2013) and the time in bytes(hex) = 34:71 (13425 in decimal) that equals on the display "06:35"

I tried to compare with epoch "1970 and 1980" and tried comparing with other time translations 32bit integer and so on. But i cannot figure out what the translate is to. Maybe someone here have seen simular and can tell maybe what encoding this is.

Best Regards
Thomas Nissen

Comment: Can you provide more information on the Modbus Register Map you are trying to read?  I would imagine the Date/Time may be stored in more than a single 16-bit register, or perhaps there is more information on proper decoding of the date/time information.  Is this register map publicly available?

Comment: This is what is send [T] and received [R]:
[T] 1E 04 01 92 00 01 93 B4 - 
BusAddress=30 [1byte], Register=4 [1byte], Address=402 [2bytes], Quantity=1 [2bytes], CRC [2bytes]

[R] 1E 04 02 43 68 1C 2C 
BusAddress=30, Register=4, BytesToCome=2, DataBytes=43:68, CRC

Comment: If i make a request on to 16bit registers (quantity=2) Then i get the bytes for both date and time in the 2 registers. 17256 and 13425.

Comment: This is the only information coming from the datasheet:
Alarm.List_1_Date - 402 - Alarm 1 Date
Alarm.List_1_Time - 402 - Alarm 1 Time Every other register i read gives me hex value equeals to 0-1 (on/off) or 0-10000 (degrees/100), 0-100 (%) or ASCII characters to show display status.

Comment: When you read these registers, do the values ever change?  If you are reading a time register and it isn't changing every minute, then something else is wrong...

Comment: No they not changed but the are properly not supposed to change becouse its a timestamp on a Alarm/Error, so i dont think its changing until next error.

Comment: I Googled those alarms and found documentation for a NILAN climate controller.  There was no information on decoding the alarm timestamp.  I would recommend calling the manufacturer directly and trying to get clarity on decoding those registers.  I have often found that device Modbus maps are hastily written and full of holes, and it will take a few calls to straighten out the data details that are important to you.  Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: Hi again Nanomurf, i received some information from the vendor about the registers. Can you help me "translate" :) it should be a a DOS filesystem time in 16bit (2x16bit date/time).

  uiTime  = (ucSecond >> 1) & 0x001F;
  uiTime |= (ucMinute & 0x003F) << 5;
  uiTime |= ucHour << 11;
 
  uiDate  =  ucDay & 0x001F;
  uiDate |= (ucMonth & 0x000F) << 5;
  uiDate |= (unsigned short int)(uiYear - 1980) << 9;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Nanomurf, i got it fixed. I "translated" and came up with this thats working :)
It gives me the following 08-11-2013 06:35:24 and thats what i wanted. Thanks for your time.

```
    Dim strDate As String = "17256"
    Dim year As String = (strDate >> 9) + 1980
    Dim month As String = (strDate And &H1E0) >> 5
    Dim day As String = strDate And &H1F

    Dim strTime As String = "13425"
    Dim hour As String = strTime >> 11
    Dim minute As String = (strTime And &H7E0) >> 5
    Dim secund As String = (strTime And &H1F) * 2

    Dim AlarmDate As String = New DateTime(CInt(year), CInt(month), CInt(day), CInt(hour), CInt(minute), CInt(secund))
```