# extract Date and Time from two 16-bit modbus registers

Tags: date, time, modbus

I'm using an ElNet energy&power meter that communicates with my processor via Modbus RTU protocol.

There are two 16-bit ElNet registers that contain information about the Date and Time (separately) in a Win Format (registers 85-86, page 6 of [this](http://www.lsa.hu/files/files/elnet_comm.pdf) document). I'm able to read these two registers. However, I'm unable to extract information about the Date and Time.

For example, Date register contains decimal value of 17841 for today's date (31/07/2015). Is there any person willing to explain me how to convert 17841 into 31/07/2015?

I have the same problem with the time. My time register contains a decimal value of 55296. Can you help me extract the time from this number?

This thread addresses the same problem:
[HEX/Decimal to date and time from modbus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20018623/hex-decimal-to-date-and-time-from-modbus)
However, I'm not sure I understand the extraction algorithm applied there. My point of operation is processor with the code written in C or C++.

Thank you very much for your time and effort to help me.

Sincerely,

Bojan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MS-DOS date/time format is described here: https://archive.is/2bVlz (was http://proger.i-forge.net/MS-DOS_date_and_time_format/OFz but is gone)

It makes sense for the 17256 value mentioned in the other question, as it translates to 2013-11-08. See here how to do it:

```
Register bit description: 0bYYYYYYYMMMMDDDDD

Registervalue: 17256 0b0100001101101000

Yearmask: 0b1111111000000000
Yearpart: 0b0100001000000000
Yearpart rightshifted 9 steps: 0b0000000000100001 = 33 years after 1980

Monthmask: 0b0000000111100000
Monthpart: 0b0000000101100000
Monthpart rightshifted 5 steps: 0b0000000000001011 = 11

Daymask: 0b0000000000011111
Daypart: 0b0000000000001000 = 8
```

Unfortunately your register value 17841 does not make sense, as it translates to 2014-13-17 (That is month 13).

Are you sure that:

- you read the correct register? (change the time setting in the instrument, and see what happens to the register value)
- you do not mix up the two bytes in the register?
- the time setting is correct?

Comment: Hi Jonas, thanks for your illustrative explanations. Let me try one more time my time settings. I will let you know the result.